# Outlook Script - Forward first line of an inbound email

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I'm trying to write a script that simply forwards the very first line of an email to another email address. The inbound emails are always formatted like:

> Line1
>
> Line2
>   Line3

You'll note that there is a carriage return after line 1. Not sure if that helps but I want the output email to have the same subject line, forwarded to a different email and the body will contain:

> Line1

I've found samples where I can look for specific strings of text, but haven't found a sample to grab the first line. Searching for specific text won't work because that first line is always different. The only thing that is common is the CR between Line 1 and Line 2.

So far I have simply:

```
Sub SendNew(Item As Outlook.MailItem)

Dim objMsg As MailItem
Set objMsg = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)

objMsg.Body = Item.Body
objMsg.Subject = Item.Subject
objMsg.Recipients.Add "person@domain.com"

objMsg.Send

End Sub
```

Could someone please assist with something i can insert to grab just the first line? Thanks much!

Comment: line1 = Split(Trim(myItem.Body), vbCrLf)(0)

Comment: Bingo! Thanks @Barney !